# Setting kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName for an NSMutableAttributedString in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

The documentation for kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName relays the following:

> **kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName**
>   The style of underlining, to be applied at render time, for the text to which this attribute applies. Value must be a CFNumber object. Default is kCTUnderlineStyleNone. Set a value of something other than kCTUnderlineStyleNone to draw an underline. In addition, the constants listed in CTUnderlineStyleModifiers can be used to modify the look of the underline. The underline color is determined by the text's foreground color.

The signature for the setAttributes function is as follows:

```
func setAttributes(attrs: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, range: NSRange)
```

The issue that I'm having is that the documentation seems to allude to the fact that **CTUnderlineStyle.Single** can (and should, in Swift) be used as a value for the **kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName** key. However, the former is a struct, and as a result does not conform to the AnyObject protocol required by the dictionaries value type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spend quite a few time on this.

The value needs to confront the `AnyObject` protocol.

Instead of using `CTUnderlineStyle.Single` use `NSNumber` like this:

```
NSNumber(int: CTUnderlineStyle.Single.rawValue)
```

Example:

```
attributedString.addAttribute(kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value:NSNumber(int: CTUnderlineStyle.Single.rawValue), range:NSRange(location:0,length:attributedString.length));
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Vojtech really appreciate you taking the time to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

in **swift 3** worked for me this code

```
let attributes:[AnyHashable : Any] = [kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName as AnyHashable:NSNumber(value:CTUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue)]
```